# Javascript how to parse JSON object dynamically with the given path

Tags: javascript, json

I need to fetch an attribute value in a JSON object dynamically, whose structure is unknown, but the path is configured. Please see the below example, thank you.

```
var perfData = {
    "data": {
        "inner":{
            "TaxiFuel": "TestVal"
        }
    }
}

var path = "data.inner.TaxiFuel";// configure value
console.log(perfData.data.inner.TaxiFuel) // This works fine, Output: TestVal
console.log(perfData.path) //?? How can I use the path variable to get the value
```

Comment: you can use prefData.path["data"]["inner"]["Taxifuel"]

Comment: you mean without knowing how many levels and  Levels names between `data` and `TaxiFuel` ?

Comment: I know the levels, ex:  var path = "data.inner.TaxiFuel";// configure value.

Comment: do `console.log( path.split('.').reduce((a,n)=>a[n], perfData) )`